# Using Ionic native InAppPurchase2 plugin with Vue

Tags: vue.js, ionic-framework, in-app-purchase, native, capacitor

I'm trying to implement in app purchases in my app, and for this I'm using InAppPurchase2 in a Ionic Vue project using [this documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/ja/v5/native/in-app-purchase-2) and [this tutorial](https://devdactic.com/ionic-in-app-purchase-capacitor), but I couldn't manage to make it work. All the examples I could find were in Angular or React, I even tried converting it, but it didn't work.

This is how I installed the plugins:

```
npm install cordova-plugin-purchase 
npm install @awesome-cordova-plugins/in-app-purchase-2
```

This is the function I'm using to initialize it:

```
import { InAppPurchase2 } from '@ionic-native/in-app-purchase-2/ngx';

export function initializeIAP() {
    console.log("[IAP] Initializing IAP.")
    console.log(InAppPurchase2)
    //IAP
    InAppPurchase2.verbosity = InAppPurchase2.DEBUG;
    console.log("[IAP] verbosity: " + InAppPurchase2.verbosity)

    InAppPurchase2.register({
        id: MY_PRODUCT_ID,
        type: InAppPurchase2.NON_CONSUMABLE,
    });

    InAppPurchase2.refresh();
}
```

But for some reason it logs "[IAP] verbosity: undefined" and then say that "register" is not a function...

I also tried using it through a variable, like

```
iap = new InAppPurchase()
```

But then it logged errors saying that the plugin wasn't installed (even if I install them again)

Answer (score 0):

In Vue you have to use

```
import { InAppPurchase2, IAPProduct } from '@ionic-native/in-app-purchase-2';
```

instead of the angular version (~/ngx)